# how to split this string mylist= '123+45+34*7-3*45/5' using re.split() to get ['123','45','34','7','3','45','5'] using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

`mylist= '123+45+34*7-3*45/5'` using `re.split()` to get `['123','45','34','7','3','45','5']` using python.

I have tried:

```
import re
print(re.split('+|-|*|/',mylist)
```

and also this

```
print(re.split(r'[+-*/]',mylist)
```

This giving me error.

I am beginner.

Comment: An alternative without regexp: `[w for w in shlex.shlex('123+45+34*7-3*45/5') if w.isnumeric()]`

Comment: print (re.split('\D+',mylist)) or print (re.split('[^0-9]',mylist))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first solution fails because `+` and `*` are regex metacharacters - if you want to use them as literals, you need to escape them. The following would have worked:

```
print(re.split(r'\+|-|\*|/',mylist)
```

Note that I used a raw string - always a good idea with regexes to reduce the number of backslashes you'd need otherwise.

Your second solution fails because `-` is a metacharacter in a character class (and there is no "range of characters between `+` and `*`). By placing it at the start or end of the character class, `-` loses its special meaning, so the following would have worked:

```
print(re.split(r'[-+*/]',mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
p = re.compile('\W+')
p.split('123+45+34*7-3*45/5')
```

output is `['123', '45', '34', '7', '3', '45', '5']`

`\W` Matches any non-alphanumeric character; this is equivalent to the class `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

For more information refer to [Python Docs for regular expressions usage](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall('\d+', string)`:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = '123+45+34*7-3*45/5'
>>> print(re.findall('\d+', string))

['123', '45', '34', '7', '3', '45', '5']
```

*Explanation:* `\d` is a digit (a character in the range 0-9), and `+` means 1 or more times. So, `\d+` is 1 or more digits.